# Apply mean filter to all images while resizing them by utf code. Working on tensor flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, filter

in the image  the code is using the UTF code for the resizing of the images  , how can i apply mean filter to all images [loading the data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMYNX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various filters available for image transformation in TensorFlow addons.
Judging from the code in your parse function, you are reading the image and you want to implement your logic inside the parse function.

Note: tensorflow_addons is a separate package and you have to install it seperately.

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

img_raw = tf.io.read_file(img_path) # byte string
img = tf.io.decode_image(img_raw) # numpy array with dtype unint8
img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32) # numpy array with dtype float32
img = tf.image.resize(img, [500,500])

plt.title("TensorFlow Logo with shape {}".format(img.shape))
_ = plt.imshow(img)
```

Output:
[image: Original Image]

Now applying mean filter using tfa.image.mean_filter2d().
You can see the documentation here: [Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/image/mean_filter2d)

Code:

```
mean = tfa.image.mean_filter2d(img, filter_shape=11)
_ = plt.imshow(mean)
```

Output:
[image: Filtered Image]

There are various other image filters in tensorflow addons.
You can check the working here: [Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/tutorials/image_ops)

Comment: i use cv2.blur to apply mean filters

Comment: It depends on your choice. Since you also had tensorflow as one of the labels I provided the solutions using tensorflow.

Comment: i used cv2. blur for mean filters , is that the corect way? whilei write down in my prase function?